# SVG - fulfill spaces between lines in flag schema

Tags: css, svg

This is my SVG code for flag schema. I want to paint empty spaces between lines with various colors. I tried to change "fill" and "stroke" attributes but nothing has changed. How can I achieve that? My code and fiddle with proper view are below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 2834.65 1755" enable-background="new 0 0 2834.65 1755" xml:space="preserve">
< rect y="-4.728" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="2834.65" height="1757.841"/>
< g>
<rect x="15.868" y="10.607" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="2802.311" height="1724.804"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="797.333" y1="10.607" x2="797.333" y2="643.455"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="797.333" y1="643.455" x2="15.868" y2="643.455"/>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="1245.221" y1="10.607" x2="1245.221" y2="643.455"/>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="1245.221" y1="643.455" x2="2818.179" y2="643.455"/>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="1246.936" y1="1112.52" x2="1246.936" y2="1735.411"/>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="1245.221" y1="1112.52" x2="2818.179" y2="1112.52"/>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="797.333" y1="1099.579" x2="797.333" y2="1735.411"/>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="797.333" y1="1099.579" x2="15.868" y2="1099.579"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zoLdduxa/1/

Comment: I am not sure how to fix your issue, but I wanted to suggest this SVG flag library for a possible solution: https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<line>` just draws a line from one point to another.  If you want your "+" shape to be filled with a colour, you have to make a shape that describes the complete continuous boundary around the outside of that shape.  Either a `<path>` element, or a `<polygon>` element would work for this example.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 2834.65 1755" enable-background="new 0 0 2834.65 1755" xml:space="preserve">
<rect y="-4.728" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="2834.65" height="1757.841"/>
<g>
 
  <rect x="15.868" y="10.607" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="2802.311" height="1724.804"/>
    <polygon fill="#ffffff"
             points="797.333,   10.607,
                     797.333,  643.455,
                      15.868,  643.455,
                      15.868, 1099.579,
                     797.333, 1099.579,
                     797.333, 1735.411,
                    1246.936, 1735.411,
                    1246.936, 1112.52,
                    2818.179, 1112.52,
                    2818.179,  643.455,
                    1245.221,  643.455,
                    1245.221,   10.607" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for guiding me toward right direction! But how did you change the code that way? I have also several other flag schemas which need to be colored (including Great Britain). Is there any program for this?

Comment: I just took the coordinates from your line endpoints and rearranged them in order around the cross shape.  If you are using a vector editor then just draw the shape as a continuous path.  You should be able to find videos explaining how to do that if you can't work it out.

Answer (score 1):

i think your schema would be better like this (Change SVG viewbox/size acordingly)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="480" width="640" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
  <path fill="#000" d="M0 0h640v480H0z"/>
  <path fill="#000" d="M0 174.545h640v130.909H0z" stroke-width="2" stroke="#fff" />
  <path fill="#000" d="M175.455 0h130.909v480H175.455z"  stroke-width="2" stroke="#fff" />
</svg>
```

The only thing is that both path-strokes will cross and one will put the other underneath. If you don't want that, create 4 squares top-left, bottom-left, top-right rectangle, bottom-right rectangle and give all 4 a stroke (care with flag borders) or you could create a cross shape as polygon and be done with it. Demo below:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="480" width="640" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
  <path fill="#000" d="M0 0h640v480H0z"/>
  <polygon fill="#000" points="0,180 180,180 180,0 300,0 300,180 640,180 640,300 300,300 300,480 180,480 180,300 0,300 z" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ktgyh3sj/1/